# python importerror no module named zope.interface twisted

Tags: python, twisted, zope

I am new in python.I installed "scrapy" but it giving error "importerror no module named zope.interface twisted".Please help me.

Thanks in advance..........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scrapy requires a few additional libraries, namely [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/) and [libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/) (and optionally [pyopenssl](http://pyopenssl.sourceforge.net/) and [simplejson](http://undefined.org/python/#simplejson)).  The [installation instructions](http://doc.scrapy.org/intro/install.html) describes how to install these libraries.

Comment: Thanks Par..I already installed all libraries according "installation instructions" but still i am getting this error...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error after following the steps scrapy suggested, mainly using pip install Scrapy. In order to install some Scrapy dependencies you will need root permision, and my mistake was creating a virtualenv for my scrapy project. Maybe you will run into the same error after following the scrapy setup steps and using virtualenv. Just dont use virtualenv.